# How to make google map 'fit to markers'?

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I am using [google-map-react](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react) to render maps in my react app.I am displaying dynamic number of markers on the map.I need to fit the view of map so that it just encloses all the markers.I went through this [thread](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react/issues/3) but found it a bit complicated.Can anyone please give me an overview of how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It happens that I had to do the exact same thing recently. I found that existing libs were more getting on my way than actually helping so I just went with writing my own component.

In case you decide going the same way - here's how to do what you want:

First - you need to get the bounds object enclosing all your markers. Here we assume that `this.state.markers` contains an array of `google.maps.Marker` objects

Your component could have the following method to do that:

```
  getObjectsBounds(){

    let objectsBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    Object.values(this.state.markers).map((marker) => {
      let lat   = parseFloat(marker.getPosition().lat());
      let long  = parseFloat(marker.getPosition().lng());
      let point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
      objectsBounds.extend(point);
    });

    return objectsBounds;
  }
```

Now we just use `fitBounds` on the above funtion's return results. Here we assume that this.map is your gmap, i.e. what `google.maps.Map( ... your args ... )` returns.

```
  fitBounds(){
    let bounds = this.getObjectsBounds();
    this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
```

Comment: Not really since I didn't get any feedback from the OP. This is what I'm using on my project so I'm pretty sure it works :)